# loop over arguments in python parser

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments

I have the following python `argparse` parser:

```
pointparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
pointparser.add_argument("-a", "--a_value", default="NaN", nargs="?",
                         type=float)
pointparser.add_argument("-b", "--b_value", default="NaN", nargs="?",
                         type=float)
...
pointparser.add_argument("-j", "--j_value", default="NaN", nargs="?",
                         type=float)
data_point = pointparser.parse_args(parameterlist)
datapoint=[data_point.a_value, data_point.b_value, data_point.c_value,
           data_point.d_value, data_point.e_value, data_point.f_value,
           data_point.g_value, data_point.h_value, data_point.i_value,
           data_point.j_value]
```

Is it possible to loop over the arguments a-j and directly store them in a list. That way, I could leave the number of arguments open, i.e. only go to `-c` or even to `-k`

Comment: Do you actually care about them being named a, b, c, etc, or do you just want the user to be able to run e.g. `python yourthing.py one two three` and get a list `['one', 'two', 'three']`?

Comment: You really shouldn't have one variable `datapoint` and another `data_point`.

Comment: The `nargs` is a little odd. There doesn't seem to be any reason to specify the options without an argument, since it accomplishes the same thing as not specifying it at all.

Comment: @chepner: It avoids an error of the program if, e.g. by mistake, no argument is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import argparse
import math

pointparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
pointparser.add_argument("-a", "--a_value", default="NaN", nargs="?",
                         type=float)
pointparser.add_argument("-b", "--b_value", default="NaN", nargs="?",
                         type=float)
pointparser.add_argument("-j", "--j_value", default="NaN", nargs="?",
                         type=float)
data_point = pointparser.parse_args()
datapoint = [value for key, value in sorted(vars(data_point).items())
             if not math.isnan(value)]
print(datapoint)  # [1.0, 2.0]
```